# Change windows 10 start menu

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

I bought a windows 10 laptop 2 years, ago and I just bought a new laptop that is much better.

The new laptops start menu, looks much different, even though they are both windows 10 home

New: (there is a apps list on the side, which I removed for personal reasons)
[image: New Start Menu]

Old:
[image: Old start menu]

Does anyone know how I can switch my old laptop to the new one, or my new laptop to the old one?

**Edit:**

The new computers version is 1903
The new computers version is 1803

How do I upgrade, because when I go to restart is does not push a upgrade

Comment: Have you tried [export-startlayout](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/startlayout/export-startlayout?view=win10-ps) and [import-startlayout](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/startlayout/import-startlayout?view=win10-ps) to see if that'd do it? What version or Windows are each of the machines which you can see by running the command `winver` are they both 1903 for example? I'm not 100% certain if that matters much depending on the differences if even applicable but good detail to disclose regardless.

Comment: @Ramhound how do I upgrade to 1903?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does anyone know how I can switch my old laptop to the new one, or my new laptop to the old one?

Since your old laptop is running Windows version 1803 you should simply upgrade to Windows version 1903.  Likewise, while there is nothing preventing you from installing Windows version 1803 on your new device, it will be unsupported come November 2019.

> How do I upgrade, because when I go to restart is does not push a upgrade

You can use the Media Creation Tool or Upgrade Assistant or Windows Update to upgrade to Windows version 1903.  If you have encountered a situation where 1903 is blocked or the upgrade is reverted due to an error that would be a different question.

> The new laptops start menu, looks much different, even though they are both windows 10 Home

The differences in the Start Menu is due to version of Windows 10 each device is running.